# Removing </p> tag after ValidationSummary control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, design-time

I use Visual Studio 2010 in ASP.NET with C# code behind.

I have an ASP.NET page with code in Source View:

```
<p>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
</p>
```

If I switch in Design View and come back to Source View in VS, it unexpectedly removes the last `</p>` automatically.

Do you have the same problem in your Visual Studio?
Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks.

P.S. Here my full code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h1>
        Create Groups Types</h1>
    <p>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="uxCreateGroupsTypesDisplayer" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
            DataKeyNames="GroupTypeId" DataSourceID="uxEntityDataSourceCreateGroupsTypes"
            DefaultMode="Insert" 
            oniteminserted="uxCreateGroupsTypesDisplayer_ItemInserted" 
            oniteminserting="uxCreateGroupsTypesDisplayer_ItemInserting">
            <Fields>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TypeGroup" SortExpression="TypeGroup">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="uxTypeGroupInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TypeGroup") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="TypeGroup field is required."
                            ControlToValidate="uxTypeGroupInput" Text="*">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uxRegularExpressionTypeGroup" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="uxTypeGroupInput" ErrorMessage="TypeGroup is too long or short. Change the field accordingly."
                            ValidationExpression="^.{4,40}$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary" SortExpression="Summary">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="uxSummaryInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorSummary" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Summary field is required."
                            ControlToValidate="uxSummaryInput" Text="*">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uxRegularExpressionSummary" runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxSummaryInput"
                            ErrorMessage="Summary is too long or short. Change the field accordingly." ValidationExpression="^.{4,256}$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" /></p> <!-- The problem is here - This tag disappear if you switch from source view to design view and back to source view -->
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="uxEntityDataSourceCreateGroupsTypes" runat="server" 
            EnableFlattening="False"
            EnableInsert="True" EntitySetName="CmsGroupsTypes">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour. Can you perhaps show a little more of your markup? Or at least explain your tag hierarchy?

Comment: Hi, I posted the code for my page. Thanks for your time on this

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't remove the `</p>` tag, it only moves it to the end of the previous line (VS doesn't like whitespace between an element content and its end tag).

Comment: I'm not sure id I understood. So in this case the <p> tag before ValidationSummary will be not clodes. Correct?

Comment: @GibboK, it is indeed closed. Look at the end of the `<asp:ValidationSummary />` line. You'll find the `</p>` tag there.

Comment: I posted here my source code BEFORE the problem occuried, if you try my code posted and you SWITCH from SOURCE VIEW to DESIGN VIEW and back to SOURCE VIEW the last tag </p> disappear. Please try it first hand. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2008, replaced:

```
<p>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" /></p>
```

With:

```
<p>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"></asp:ValidationSummary></p>
```

This works, although does not agree with the closing tag in markup. Rendering is correct though in IE8.

Why does this summary control need to be enclosed in a paragraph tag? The Validation Summary renders as a block element.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Design View to edit markup, always use Source View, i.e. markup itself to edit markup.

IMO Design View just a simple, read-only, verify-purpose view.

Comment: were you able to reproduce my problem on your visual studio? thanks